# Позиционирование H1 в слайдере

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт https://studentprograms.ru/ на главной есть слайдер с текстом Детские каникулы 2018. Как позиционировать этот текст, чтобы он расположился в правом нижнем углу слайдера?

Answer (score 0):

Слайдеру задать position: relative.

Тексту

```
h1{
position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```

В классе

`.ls-slide > *{ }`

уберите top и left.

Comment: Я так пробовал. Не получилось что-то

Comment: @Kolhoznik, .ls-slide > *{
} 
уберите top и left и все получится.